How to access SPD by SMBUS on Windows PC?
I want to access the DDR5 SPD EEPROM by SMBus on Windows PC, but my knowledge in this area is quite limited. So, I am programming with WinRing0, but I seem to be unable to read it correctly. All of Bytes i Read are 0xFF，How can i fix this?
Below is my C++ code.
1)Get SMBUS address
DWORD smbus_bus = 0x00; 
DWORD smbus_device = 0x1F; 
DWORD smbus_func = 0x04; 
DWORD pci_base_address = PciBusDevFunc(smbus_bus, smbus_device, smbus_func); 
DWORD smbus_address = 0;//BAR 5 
if (!ReadPciConfigDwordEx(pci_base_address, 0x20, &smbus_address)) {    
 } 
else {     
    smbus_address &= 0xFFFE;
 }

2)Set PAGE
#define SMBHSTCMD 3
#define SMBHSTADD 4
#define SMBHSTDAT 5
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTCMD, 0x00);
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTADD, 0x6C); // Set SPD Page Address
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTCNT, 0x44);

3)Read SPD Data
#define SMBHSTSTS 0
#define SMBHSTCNT 2
#define SMBHSTCMD 3
#define SMBHSTADD 4
#define SMBHSTDAT 5
DWORD SPD_ADDRESS = 0x50;
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTCMD, (UINT8)(offset & 0xFF)); // SMBus uses 8 bit commands
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTADD, (SPD_ADDRESS << 1) | 0x01); // read from spd
WriteIoPortByte(smbus_address + SMBHSTCNT, 0x48); // Start + Byte Data Read
BYTE data = ReadIoPortByte(SMBUS_ADDRESS + SMBHSTDAT);

